# JSON view not working after implementing authorization in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Since I implemented authorization in my cakephp project, it seens I can't access my views with JSON anymore. Do I have to set a specific setting anywhere to make this work again?
I was hoping adding autoComplete to the allowedActions and isAuthorized would do the trick

app\Controller\BrandsController.php (stripped from unnecessary code)

```
<?php
    App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility');

    class BrandsController extends AppController {
        public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
        public $components = array('Session', 'RequestHandler');

        public function beforeFilter() {
            parent::beforeFilter();
            $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('autoComplete');
        }

        public function isAuthorized($user) {
            if ($this->action === 'view' || $this->action === 'index' || $this->action === 'autoComplete') {
                return true;
            }
            return parent::isAuthorized($user);
        }

        public function autoComplete($name = null)
        {
            if(!$name)
            {
                $name = @$this->params->query['name'];
            }

            $name = Sanitize::paranoid($name, array(' '));

            if (!$name || empty($name))
            {
                new NotFoundException(__('Invalid searchquery'));
            }
            else
            {

                $objects = $this->Brand->find('list', 
                    array(
                        'conditions' => array("Brand.name LIKE" => "%" . $name . "%")
                    )
                );
                $this->layout = 'ajax';
                $this->RequestHandler->setContent('json', 'application/json' ); 
                $this->set(compact('objects'));
                $this->render('json/output_json');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

app\View\Brands\json\output_json.ctp

```
<?php
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
    echo json_encode($objects);
?>
```

Call

```
<?php 
    $brandsAutoCompleteUrl = Router::url(array('controller' => 'brands', 'action' => 'autoComplete')); 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON('<?php echo $brandsAutoCompleteUrl; ?>', { name: 'test' }, function(data) {
            // never called
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my Chrome debug window it sais

```
GET http://localhost/cakephp/brands/autoComplete?name=tes 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

When I call this url from my browser directly, I get the expected results

Comment: With error500 messages, the first thing you should check is the log files of your webserver, it might not be related to the auth component.

Comment: Also, not directly related to your problem, but you need to update your code for CakePHP 2.3. `$this->params` is only present for backwards compatibility, you should use the request-object; `$this->request->query('name')` (and please, don't use `@` to suppress errors). The requestHandler is not required either, use the 'response' object in stead. More info here; http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#dealing-with-content-types and here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

Comment: Some more errors in your code: you don't 'throw' your Exception, just create it (which may cause an error on its own), and you didn't disable autoRender, which will probably cause errors as well

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers, I just started working with CakePHP so this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this problem by replacing

```
$this->RequestHandler->setContent('json', 'application/json' );
```

by

```
$this->response->type(array('json' => 'application/json'));
```

Answer (score 1):

correct allowing is

```
$this->Auth->allow('view', 'index');
```

This can be done only in a controller that is owner of allowed actions -
[Link to documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public)

Also - in firefox firebug or in chrome you can view response for your 500 HTTP error that is usually an html code with an exact CakePHP error - investigate this first.

Why do you add components and helpers in this controller instead of AppController? This components are common for any controller - it is reasonable to put them to AppController.
And if you haven't noticed - all helpers and components of AppController are merged with helpers and components of child controllers. You can't switch off Auth component by replacing components in child controller.

Recommendation:
Avoid using of '@' for code like `@$this->params->query['name'];`. Use `!empty($this->params->query['name'])` in 'if' condition

If you don't know: `empty($name) == !$name`, also `!$name` can trigger error in variable $name is not initiated - http://www.php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php (1st table)

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers, I found the bug by lookin in the log files. Can't believe I didn't check there myself before asking it here